# Data transfer from arduino to raspberry pi wirelessly?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, wireless, arduino

How do I send data to raspberry pi connected over wifi from arduino connected to a laptop which is in turn connected to the same wifi network as raspberry pi?

Answer (score 1):

What is it that you want to send ? If it is just sending some files, Raspberry Pi can be set-up as as `ssh` server and you connect to it from your laptop with a `ssh` client. See here for more on [Raspberry Pi `ssh`](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh).

If you are looking to send data in a client-server fashion, then obviously, a server should be running on the Pi and the appropriate client on the laptop and the data transformation for the application layer protocol.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to know how to send data in client-server fashion. I have installed LAMP server on my PI and I have used phpmyadmin to set up the database. How to use laptop as a client for data transformation?

Answer (score 0):

As cogitoergosum says, you can connect the laptop to the raspberry pi over ssh, and you can connect the raspberry pi to the laptop with serial commands.

You can then use [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) to connect the arduino and the wifi together on the laptop.

If you want to remove the overhead of the laptop to remove it sometime, look in to the X-Bee shields. There is a wifi one there but they can be costly.